# Increasing the next value in a column so all the values are increasing according to unique ID column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I got some data such as this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), values = c(12, 
13, 13, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want something like this

```
structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), values2 = c(12, 
13, 13.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 8, 8.5, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want to check if they values in the values column for each ID are in increasing.If two values are equal then increase the second value by 0.5. Similary if the next value is smaller increase it by o.5.

Comment: Sorry that was by mistake. Please check the edit. Thanks

Comment: what would your output be like, if `values` in row 6 is 6.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To My dear Friend @AnilGoyal**

We can use `accumulate` function for this purpose:

- I created a conditional statement comparing current value `.y` to the accumulated/ previous value `.x`
- If the current value is greater than the previous value, the result will be the current value, otherwise we add `0.5` to the previous value
- Bear in mind that in every accumulation `.x` represents the previous value while `.y` represents the new/ current value

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(values = accumulate(values, 
                             ~ if(.y > .x) {
                               .y
                             } else {
                               .x + 0.5
                             }))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id values
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1   12  
2     1   13  
3     1   13.5
4     2    6  
5     2    6.5
6     2    7  
7     3    8  
8     3    8.5
9     3    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `rle()` to create sequences of `.5` steps.

```
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$id, \(x) {
  v <- x$value
  d <- diff(v)
  if (any(d < 0)) o <- seq(v[1], length.out=length(v), by=.5)
  else if (any(d == 0)) {
    r <- rle(v)
    o <- unlist(Map(\(y, z) seq(y, length.out=z, by=.5), r$values, r$lengths))
  }
  return(setNames(data.frame(x$id, o), names(x)))
}))
#     id values
# 1.1  1   12.0
# 1.2  1   13.0
# 1.3  1   13.5
# 2.1  2    6.0
# 2.2  2    6.5
# 2.3  2    7.0
# 3.1  3    8.0
# 3.2  3    8.5
# 3.3  3    9.0
```

Comment: It's a pleasure to meet you Mr. Jay.sf

Comment: Jay sir, the output in row 5 is not as desired/expected.